# How to get a specific item from a listview items at onClick event?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a chat app using Firebase.

My problem is that I am showing all the users in a listview from Firebase Database. I want when I click on any user from the list, then the email of that user should be shown in a toast.

In the listview, I show the name and email of the user in separate textviews. So how do I get the email textview's data on the clicked item?

Please help or suggest an alternate solution.

[image]

This is my code:

```
    users = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userlist1);

    users.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(UserList.this, OneChat.class);
            String p = "p";
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i+""+users.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent.putExtra(p,i);
            startActivity(intent);

        }});



    List<user> allu = new ArrayList<>();
    uad = new useradapter(this, R.layout.item_user, allu);
    users.setAdapter(uad);

    firebaseAuth0 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    FirebaseUser user0 = firebaseAuth0.getCurrentUser();
    if (user0 != null) {
        // User is signed in
        attachDatabaseReadListener();
    } else {
        // User is signed out
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }


    attachDatabaseReadListener();

}

private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
    if (mChildEventListener == null) {

        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                user userf = dataSnapshot.getValue(user.class);
                uad.add(userf);
                progressDialog.hide();
                //mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                // tvw=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                //tvw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        udbr.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);


    }}

private void detachDatabaseReadListener() {
    if (mChildEventListener != null) {
        udbr.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        mChildEventListener = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: [take reference from here may be you will get something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744080/after-filter-listview-i-am-not-able-to-get-actual-position-of-item-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your allu list contain all the users.. make this list a global variable and then in your onItemSelectListener do something like this

```
users.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), allu.get(i).getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserList.this, OneChat.class);
            intent.putExtra("p",i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
```